# outlook contact Outlook.AddressEntry type as EX and SMTP

Tags: outlook, smtp, exchange-server, contacts

Existing code Outlook 2010 interop dll get

```
Dim f_objAddressEntry As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry
```

`f_objAddressEntry.Type` returns as `"EX"` for users within the domain.

Recently few users were moved to O365 and Outlook 2013.
`f_objAddressEntry.Type` returns `"SMTP"`.
Because of this many outlook plug-ins apps functionalities failed.

Please suggest when TYPE will be "EX" or "SMTP".

Answer (score 1):

The user must be in the same Exchange domain and be visible in your GAL container to be resolvable to an EX type address entry.